# What will be my URL if soapAction is URN:something?

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

[image: The image shows the WSDL for web serice i have created and i am getting the soapAction as "URN:authentication" authentication is my method name.]

The above image shows the WSDL for web serice i have created and i am getting the soapAction as "URN:authentication" authentication is my method name

I want to know the url for soapAction as i am getting null point exception while connecting to webservice using android. 
I have create web service using AXIS 2 .

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText username, Password;

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://nepal.blue_book.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.104:8088/Blue_Book/services/Login_service?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:authentication";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            loginAction();

        }
    });
}

public void loginAction() {
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textusername);
    Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textpassword);




    if (username.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter User Name",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else if (Password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Password",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textusername);
        String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
        EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textpassword);
        String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

        Log.i("user name ", user_Name);
        Log.i("user password ", user_Password);

      //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
        unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
        unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
        unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
        request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

      //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
        passwordProp.setName("password");
        passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
        passwordProp.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(passwordProp);

        Log.i("request ....", request.toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Log.i("test .........", "hello 0");

        try{
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.i("test test.........", "hello 1");
               SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();



               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Log.d("result ........", response.toString());
              /* TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
               result.setText(response.toString());*/

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("erros ......", e.getMessage().toString());


        }
       }

    }
```

the above image is the android code to connect to soap service. and i am getting always a null point exception as control is going to catch part.
[image: log cat error]

the above image is the logcat error

Comment: SOAP web services expose only one endpoint URL that does not change because of the SOAPAction HTTP header parameter. What's the endpoint address of your web service?

Comment: And one more thing. Please post your code as actual code not print screens. It's easier to index and picked up by searches of other users having a similar problem.

Comment: your soap_action="urn:authentication" and you are not getting null pointer exception due to it. paste your android webservice code here.

Comment: @Bogdan - Please find the end point address <wsdl:service name="Login_service"><wsdl:port name="Login_serviceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:Login_serviceSoap11Binding"><soap:address location="http://localhost:8088/Blue_Book/services/Login_service.Login_serviceHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/></wsdl:port>                                                        <wsdl:port name="Login_serviceHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:Login_serviceSoap12Binding"><soap12:address location="http://localhost:8088/Blue_Book/services/Login_service.Login_serviceHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/></wsdl:port>

Comment: @Bogdan - <wsdl:port name="Login_serviceHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:Login_serviceHttpBinding"><http:address location="http://localhost:8088/Blue_Book/services/Login_service.Login_serviceHttpEndpoint/"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service>       These are the address i found for endpoint in my webservice wsdl

Comment: @Bogdan -  I have added the code above for connecting android with database using Ksoap.Please tell me what is wrong with my code ?? As i am always getting null point exception

Comment: @kingAm - I have added the above code for connecting android with database using Ksoap.Please tell me what is wrong with my code ?? As i am always getting null point exception

Comment: Above code look fine to me. For testing, Can you hardcode username and password at unameProp.setValue(user_Name) and passwordProp.setValue(user_Password) and try to run your code. may be your username and password is not coming till here.
Or you can debug your code with breakpoints to know exactly where are you getting this null pointer exception.

Comment: @kingAm - As per your suggestion i have debug the code and found the error at " androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);". Please help me to solve this issue .

Comment: try that, hardcoding username and password and lets see what do we get..

Comment: @kingAm -  Even i give hardcore value same problem.The value is coming proper i saw while debugging. There is no issue with value. I think there is some problem with soapAction string .I google it soapAction =http:// others are writing.How to find soapAction like that.I am getting urn:authentication.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47156/discussion-between-kingam-and-anandjaisy)

Comment: @kingAm -  Hey i have solve the issue . I was using emulator 4.2.2. Which doesn't support this code. So, i change my code in ASYNCTASK and problem us solve. Now every things is working fine.

Comment: Great.good to know these small things.Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.104:8088/Blue_Book/services/Login_service?wsdl";
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://nepal.blue_book.com";
```

try this,

```
 private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.104:8088/Blue_Book/services/Login_service";
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://nepal.blue_book.com/";
```

Comment: The problem was with the android version.For 2.2 version we can use this code but for 3 and above we cann't use this code for that we need to use ASYNCTASK . Connectivity cann't be use in main thread. so need to change the thread.